# Restoring from new to old

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an iPad running iOS 15 and also one running iOS 10 (not upgradeable). Can I use the iOS 10 iPad as a backup for the newer one?

Comment: What do you mean with "use as backup"?

Answer (score 2):

You **can** go forward, restoring backups made on previous versions of iOS
on to devices with newer versions of iOS.

You **can not** go backwards, restoring backups made on newer versions of iOS
on to devices with previous versions of iOS.